# Check acceptance of NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Tags: ios, ios8, ibeacon

I'm developing an application for iOS that deals with beacons and location management.
In iOS 8, the application must include "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" key in the plist file, which will show in the app while launching to get the user's permission to enable location tracking.
How can I detect whether the user accepted or not? I want to make a decision on that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect this by implementing the following method in the class setup as your CLLocationManager delegate (implementing the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol)

Example in Swift:

```
// MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    // check status to see if we’re authorized
    let authorized = (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse)
    // handle acceptance... 
}
```

Objective C Example:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    BOOL isAuthorized = status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse;
    // handle acceptance..        
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it now, but if it's possible to do it in Objective C, I'd appreciate it. I still didn't tackle Swift.

Comment: Ok np, would be great if you can accept my answer too. Thx

Comment: Just did. Sorry it didn't allow me before.